# link error d3d.lib in directx

Tags: directx

It's so weird that my program.

I study directx and I usually use tutorials on my practice.

this time I want to make whole project on my own.

So I make project and set the Link setting and directx directory.

but my program doesn't work!.

error said cannot open file 'd3d.lib'.

I set the option the same as tutorial, there's no difference.
and the code is same, cut and paste.

the only thing different is whether I make or on tutorial.

I need your help T.T

I use directx9 and SDK is Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010).
My OS is window 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not opening **d3d.lib** because there's no **d3d.lib**, It is **d3d9.lib** which you need to link.

Add this in your source code.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d9.lib")
```